# Symfony2 create form from collection

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, types

I need to create a form to edit a list of entities. This is different from the classic use case (and all the examples I found) where we have an entity which as nested entities.

In my case, I want to use:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(
        new MyType(),
        mycollectionofobjects
    );
```

So the form needs to handle a collection of objects (in my case, a propel collection).

In the classic case, we can use :

```
$formBuilder->add(
            'getTheCollection',
            "collection", etc...
```

So, from the main objects, the subforms are build using the data of getTheCollection but, with no main entity, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I use to follow for this kind of scenario is the following

- Create an entity that will not persisted to DB, of course, and represent only a container. Something like

  ```
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  class YourTypeCollector
  {
      protected $your_type_colletion;

      public function __construct() 
      {
          $this->your_type_colletion = new ArrayCollection();
      }

      public function setYourTypeCollection(ArrayCollection $yourTypeCollection)
      {
          $this->your_type_collection = $yourTypeCollection
      }

      public function getYourTypeCollection()
      {
          return $this->your_type_collection;
      }
  }
  ```
- Create `YourTypeCollectorForm`

  ```
  class YourTypeCollectorFormType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder->add('your_type_collection', 'collection', array(
              'type' => new YourTypeType()
          );
      }

     public function getName()
     {
         return 'your_type_collector_form';
     }

     public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
     {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'data_class' => 'Path\To\Your\Type\Collector',
              'cascade_validation' => true, //!Important
         ));
      }
  }
  ```
- Instantiate it into controller and use it like "normal" other forms that have a collection

  ```
  $your_type_colletor = new YourTypeCollector();
  $your_type_collector->setYourTypeCollection(//an array collection here);
  $form = $this->createForm(new YourTypeCollectorType());
  ```

I'm not sure that's the best approach to this problem, but I'm sure that works as I currently use it into my old project

Comment: Thanks, I did this way with a fake root object that only have a method 'getChild', then when I create the subform I give the parameter 'child' and that's all. I'm not sure that this is the best way, I have curious to see if there are better (more 'beautiful') solutions ?

Comment: You can just use an array instead of creating a special collection object.

Comment: @Cerad: I was pretty sure of the method you're showing here, and is obvious. But, as I told here, this was a solution that I used for old project and for this answer I just copy/pasted/adapted here :)

Comment: Yep.  I think I did the same thing some time ago until I realized that an array would work just fine.

Comment: @Cerad: you know the process, don't you?

Problem -> working code -> good code -> perfect code :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility may be this (believed to be adaptable):

Given there exists an entity named Collection that contains a set of Objects, create a form view that enables editing of all (or selected) Objects.

1)  Create a form type for a single Object:

```
class CollectionType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('object')
            ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'collection';
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'YourBundle\Entity\Collection',
        ));
    }
```

2)  Create a form type for a set of Objects

```
class ObjectsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('objects', 'collection', ['type' => new CollectionType(),
                    ])
                ))
            ;
    }
```

3) Instantiate form in controller

```
public function editObjectsAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $objects = $em->getRepository("YourBundle:Collection")->findAll();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ObjectsType(), array('objects' => $objects));
    ...
}
```

[Hoping I've properly generalized my use of this solution!]

For a "real world" application see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953858/how-to-create-a-form-with-multiple-rows-of-one-entity-in-symfony2/27954649#27954649).