# Use the same entity form but two times in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I would like to use the same entity form but two times (to modify two differents properties of my entity). By example, I have a entity User, I create a form to modify the name and another to modify the first name on the same page (just an idiot example). If I submit the first form, it said me that I have extra fields (that is normal). I tried to change the action of the second form with setAction by example but i don't know how to retrieve the form in my controller action.

I started with this code :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('name', TextareaType::class, array("required" => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' =>'Enregistrer'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('myroute');
        }
        $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->add('fname', TextareaType::class, array("required" => false))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' =>'Enregistrer'))
            ->getForm();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953858/how-to-create-a-form-with-multiple-rows-of-one-entity-in-symfony2

Comment: I checked this link but me I want two differents forms but linked with the same entity.

Comment: if you want to two different form, use different object for User class. ``$user2 = New User();`` And use in twig ``{{ form(form2) }}`` tag.